# Cannot make complete POST when including Dropzone form in a Django form

Tags: javascript, django, forms, post, dropzone.js

This is definitely in my all time top 5 most killing issues! 
I have a ModelForm in Django which is working fine. The thing is that I want to add an extra field to this form - small Dropzone.js area for image uploads. With the given code example the dropzone preview DIV is properly embedded in the main form. To achieve this of course I have programmatically initialized the Dropzone.

If I comment  `myDropzone.processQueue();` the submit button submits the regular form to the view, but without the image uploaded with Dropzone. However, if `processQueue()` is executed, it overrides the main form submitting action and only the images are submitted. The rest content is of course ignored.

I just want to submit the image among the rest input fields and I want to embed Dropzone in my Django form because if I make the entire form a Dropzone one and add the input fields there...the entire form is shown as drag&drop area and the styling is also messed up.

To make it more complicated, I have extra DB table for the images, but my view is prepared to extra handle the images from the request and to process them to the database.
Next to that, I had to manually provide CSRF in Dropzone in an ugly way (with `params: {..}`) as the one in the form template engine is not recognized by Dropzone (because it is obviously in a different form) :(

Here is the template:

```
<h1 class="asdf-page-title">
    Add Type
</h1>
<form id="gift-form" class="dropzone-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}


    {{ g_form.title }}

    <p class="asdf-form-title">Select Type:</p>
    <div class="asdf-form-pic-select row collapse-outer-space ">
        {% for choice in g_form.asdf_type %}
            <div class="col-4">
                <label class="type-{{ choice.choice_label }}">
                    {{ choice.tag }}
                    <span>{% trans choice.choice_label %}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <p class="asdf-form-title">Price:</p>
    <div class="asdf-type row collapse-outer-space ">
        <div class="col-4">
            {{ g_form.total_price }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            {{ g_form.currency }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <p class="asdf-form-title">Description:</p>
    {{ g_form.description }}

    <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>

    <p>
        <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="{{ action_btn }}"
    </p>

</form>

<link href="{% static 'admin-users/js/ckeditor/samples/css/samples.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="{% static 'admin-users/css/dropzone.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="{% static 'admin-users/js/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-users/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-users/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            var myyDropzone = new Dropzone("div#my-awesome-dropzone", {
                    url: "#",
                    params: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken')},
                    autoProcessQueue: false,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    maxFilesize: 256 * 4 * 2,
                    maxFiles: 3,
                    uploadMultiple: true,
                    parallelUploads: 10,

                    init: function() {
                        var myDropzone = this,
                            addButton = document.querySelector("#submit");

                        // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
                        addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                            e.preventDefault();
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
                        });

                        // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
                        // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
                        this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
                            // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
                            // Hide the success button or the complete form.
                        });
                        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                            // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
                            // Redirect user or notify of success.
                        });
                        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
                            // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
                            // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
                        });
                    },
                    sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
                        // Along with the file, shall I append all fields from the form above in the formData?
                    }
            });
    });
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, the issue is resolved, check my answer below. It's been almost a year, so I tried to paste and adjust the working code. Could you give it a try and let me know if you need help or further explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We solved this by making two requests to the server: One Post for the regular Django form and all its data and one Dropzone Ajax for the uploaded images, if any.

This is achieved by adding the uploaded `images` to the `formdata` in the `sending` function of `Dropzone`.

If there are any uploaded images, `myDropzone.processQueue()` will be called, otherwise we will manually submit the form in the JavaScript with `$(".dropzone-form").submit()`.

If `myDropzone.processQueue()` is executed, then we hook into the `Dropzone` event `successmultiple` and do `$(".dropzone-form").submit()` after one second. Why we are doing this? Well, Dropzone will wait until all images are uploaded, then it will immediately fire `successmultiple`. If we submit the form there directly, the user will miss the great animation of Dropzone, which shows the putting of green ticks on all uploaded images. The animation lasts approximately a second, hence the delay. For now I have not discovered a better way to do this than to set timeout one second.

Here is the code:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

if ($("#my-awesome-dropzone").length > 0){
    var myyDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
        url: "some_url",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        method: "post",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFilesize: 256 * 4 * 10,
        maxFiles: 3,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 10,

        init: function () {
            var myDropzone = this;
            var addButton = $("#submit-btn");

            // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
            addButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                } else {
                    $(".dropzone-form").submit();
                }
            });

            this.on("successmultiple", function (files, response) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".dropzone-form").submit();
                }, 1000);
            });
        },
        sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'));
            formData.append("image", file.name);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: great thanks ! 
I've just changed var addButton = $("#submit-btn"); by addButton = document.querySelector("#submit");

Comment: Thanks, added my fields to the formData variable by: formData.append("description", $('#id_description').val());

Comment: if we are making two requests to the server how would we track that which record associates with which image  ?

Comment: To Mr. Usman's point above, I would love to see the view on this.